# Coordinate pairs distances

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, distance

I am new to GIS and have the following question. My shapefile has several coordinate pairs (x1, y1, x2, y2) and I would like to calculate the distances between the points within one go.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Cartesian distance is quite easy to calculate, but you'd need to provide your preferred programming interface (C#, Java, Python) to get specific assistance (edit the question to include target language and your initial attempt to solve this in that language). More detail on the meaning of distances between points may be useful as well (a sketch, maybe, showing two features and which distance you want).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) What geometry is your shapefile that it has 2 coordinate pairs stored in one table? Is it a polyline with the coordinates representing the ends of each line? You could add a 'distance' field to the attribute table (type - double) and Calculate Geometry on the new field to get the line lengths in whichever units you would like.

2) Another option if your shapefile is not structured as above would be the XY to Line geoprocessing tool. You can specify your starting coordinate pair fields and ending coordinate pair fields, and the tool will create lines between the points in a new feature class.

Then, in your new polyline layer, add a field to the attribute table named 'distance' and calculate as mentioned above.

Finally use the Spatial Join geoprocessing tool to add the line distance attributes back to your original shapefile.

3) An alternative method to 2 (that is a bit more complicated, but does all of the work on your original shapefile) could be using some trig functions on the attribute table; such as in this link: http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/47195-Calculate-distance-between-two-points

Comment: XY to Line does exactly what I was searching. To clarify, my data is a just a table with 4 columns. Thank you!